# Shortened import can't see type in provide inject Vue 3.3 and Vite

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

I have an file with provide: `notification.hook.ts`:

```
export const NOTIFICATION_PROVIDE: InjectionKey<NotificationProvide> = Symbol(PROVIDE_INJECT.NOTIFICATION)

// code...

provide(NOTIFICATION_PROVIDE, {
  message,
  setNotification,
})
```

In vue component I import this file:

```
import { NOTIFICATION_PROVIDE } from '../hooks/notification.hook'

const { setNotification } = inject(NOTIFICATION_PROVIDE)
```

Here everythink works correct, but when I change import to:

```
import { NOTIFICATION_PROVIDE } from '@/hooks/notification.hook'
```

Webstorm show error:

> Vue: Property  setNotification  does not exist on type  {}

I added in file `vite-env.d.ts`:

```
declare module '*.hook'
```

but still I have this same error.

EDIT:

vite.config.ts:

```
import { rmSync } from 'node:fs'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import electron from 'vite-plugin-electron'
import renderer from 'vite-plugin-electron-renderer'
import pkg from './package.json'
import { resolve } from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({ command }) => {
  rmSync('dist-electron', { recursive: true, force: true })

  const isServe = command === 'serve'
  const isBuild = command === 'build'
  const sourcemap = isServe || !!process.env.VSCODE_DEBUG

  return {
    plugins: [
      vue(),
      electron([
        {
          // Main-Process entry file of the Electron App.
          entry: 'electron/main/index.ts',
          onstart(options) {
            if (process.env.VSCODE_DEBUG) {
              console.log(
                /* For `.vscode/.debug.script.mjs` */ '[startup] Electron App',
              )
            } else {
              options.startup()
            }
          },
          vite: {
            build: {
              sourcemap,
              minify: isBuild,
              outDir: 'dist-electron/main',
              rollupOptions: {
                external: Object.keys(
                  'dependencies' in pkg ? pkg.dependencies : {},
                ),
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          entry: 'electron/preload/index.ts',
          onstart(options) {
            // Notify the Renderer-Process to reload the page when the Preload-Scripts build is complete,
            // instead of restarting the entire Electron App.
            options.reload()
          },
          vite: {
            build: {
              sourcemap,
              minify: isBuild,
              outDir: 'dist-electron/preload',
              rollupOptions: {
                external: Object.keys(
                  'dependencies' in pkg ? pkg.dependencies : {},
                ),
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ]),
      // Use Node.js API in the Renderer-process
      renderer({
        // nodeIntegration: true,
        resolve: {
          serialport: { type: 'cjs' },
          got: { type: 'esm' },
        },
      }),
    ],
    server: (() => {
      const url = new URL(pkg.debug.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL)
      const VSCODE_DEBUG = process.env.VSCODE_DEBUG
      const port = VSCODE_DEBUG ? url.port : 8524
      return {
        host: url.hostname,
        port: +port,
      }
    })(),
    clearScreen: false,
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      },
    },
  }
})
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["declaration.d.ts"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

tsconfig.node.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts", "package.json", "electron", "src"]
}
```

Comment: "Webstorm show error" - does it occur otherwise? Because this seems to be IDE problem and this is probably the case for support. Make sure it works the same in .ts and .vue files, this can help to narrow down the problem. `declare module '*.hook'` is incorrect because this is .hook.ts module, not .hook . It's unknown how aliases are configured in your case

Comment: You have right, it's TS error. I checked it in VSCode and I have this same error. So It's not problem Webstorm. I edit `vite-env.d.ts` I added: `declare module '*.ts'`  and change import to: `import { NOTIFICATION_PROVIDE } from '@/hooks/notification.hook.ts'` but I have this same error

Comment: You don't need declare module here. Please, provide vite and ts configs, the question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve